# How to clear an array?

Tags: php

In a loop I want to clear an array at the end of each iteration of the loop :

```
$tab = array();
...
for($i=1; $i<=5; $i++)
{
    if ($regle_delegation_oper[$i] != "" && $regle_delegation_cond[$i] != "")
    {
        $tab['lien_id'] = $lien_id;
        $tab['regle_deleg_oper'] = $regle_delegation_oper[$i];
        $tab['regle_deleg_cond'] = $regle_delegation_cond[$i];
        $rd->ajouter($tab);
        // here I want to clear the $tab array
    }
}
```

So how to clear the $tab array ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can initalize the array when the loop starts:

```
...
for($i=1; $i<=5; $i++)
{
    $tab = array(); // This will clear the $tab array at each iteration
    if ($regle_delegation_oper[$i] != "" && $regle_delegation_cond[$i] != "")
    {
        $tab['lien_id'] = $lien_id;
        $tab['regle_deleg_oper'] = $regle_delegation_oper[$i];
        $tab['regle_deleg_cond'] = $regle_delegation_cond[$i];
        $rd->ajouter($tab);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Can't you just do something like:

```
$tab = array();
```

Comment: So I don't declare it before the loop but inside the loop ?

Comment: You declare it at both places. The second time you're just setting `$tab` back to an empty array.

Answer (score 2):

```
$tab = array();
for($i=1; $i<=5; $i++){

    if ($regle_delegation_oper[$i] != "" && $regle_delegation_cond[$i] != "")
    {
        $tab['lien_id'] = $lien_id;
        $tab['regle_deleg_oper'] = $regle_delegation_oper[$i];
        $tab['regle_deleg_cond'] = $regle_delegation_cond[$i];
        $rd->ajouter($tab);
        unset($tab);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$tab = array();
```

or

```
unset($tab);
```